# IsRegistered returning wrong results

Tags: php

Alright so I am basically trying to check if user already exists inside the table Users but no matter what is always says they do not exist.

Also I want to conduct case INSENSITIVE check so I dont have people like admin and Admin

```
private function isRegistered($username) {
    $sql = $this->connect();
    $username = $sql->real_escape_string($username);
    $res = $sql->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$username."'");
    $rows = $res->num_rows;
    $sql->close();

    return ($rows >= 1) ? true : false;
}
```

Also this is how I check if they are registered or not

```
if($this->isRegistered($username)) return "user_taken";
```

EDIT: I am also using UTF-8 for my username

Comment: in your function remove `$sql->close();` and make `if ($rows > 0) ? return true : return false;` and u check it in script `if ($this->isRegistered($username) == true) echo 'username in use';`

Comment: are u using function outside of script ? because your function is private

Answer (score 0):

I've changed coalition to utf8_general_ci on my users table and it works now. I didnt know UTF-8 by default is case sensitive